# Scrapy: how to solve the "empty" item in html due to a foreign language symbol?

Tags: scrapy

One of the scrapy-ed items seems contain no content in HTML.  In MySQL database, it does have content including a non-regular `-` (dash) that is slightly longer.  It could be a dash symbol from Chinese input, or something similar. I am copy it below, not sure whether it will keep the original form. The web link is [here](http://careers.ascp.org/jobs/7494851/gi-hospitalist-chattanooga-tennessee) and this non-regular dash is in the title and the beginning of the description.

```
**Hospitalist – Chattanooga**
```

To further prove it, the export CVS file from MySQL convert this weird dash to `?€?`. Most likely this weird symbol causes the non-display problem.

I want to either delete this weird symbol or replace it with a `,` or a regular dash.  Where can it be done? During Scrapy?  Or in MySQL?  Sorry this is not a specific coding question.  I need some guidance before figuring out any codes for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The long dash is called an EM dash [fileformat - EM dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)
The reason you are seeing it is likely due to the chosen encoding.

Try setting a different encoding or replacing the EM dash with the , sign as you mentioned in your question.

In php you can do so with the following code:

```
str_replace(chr(151), ',' $input);
```